# Image upload to Firebase storage failed on storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

My Angular app allows the user to upload an image to firebase CDN. This has worked up until the other day. After my last deployment which did not touch the image code, I get this error on the storage method:

```
firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.storage is not a function
```

The code is here:

```typescript
    import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
    ...
    const storagePathname = `${storageLogos}${this.account.accountId}-${selectedImageFile.name}`;
    const logoStorageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(storagePathname)
    await logoStorageRef.put(selectedImageFile).then(async snapshot => {
    ... do some other stuff ...
    }
```

Did something change on Firebase's side that I did not catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid...

As I was typing "did not change the image code" in the question, that nagging voice in my head said that's the FIRST thing you'd check in someone else's code. And of course, it was. This

`import * as firebase from 'firebase';`

was changed to this:

`import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`

And sure enough, that was the problem!